Reference to the result that each proper subgroup of $S_n$, apart from $A_n$, has index at least n?
In the book "Permutation Groups" by Dixon and Mortimer (chapter 5.2) it's stated that "An early observation in the theory of permutation groups was that, apart from $A_n$, each proper subgroup of $S_n$ has index at least $n$." Is there a citable reference of this result together with a proof?

A proof is here. Does this satisfy you?

No, I would like to have a reference to this result, that one can cite.

You can cite Exercise 3.25 from Rotman's book.

You can also cite stackexchange or mathoverflow nowadays ( I have seen this at least).
